# I am trying upload a file using mulesoft via Java code to a folder getting 404 file not found error

Tags: java, google-drive-api, mule, google-api-java-client, service-accounts

Using service account in Mulesoft where the service account has full read and write permissions on the folder, I can upload files when I don't specify the folder as parents in the code but when I specify the parents field it replies back with file not found error.

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
                fileMetadata.setName(filename);
                fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(folderId));
                java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File(pathOfFile);
                FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(extension, filePath);
               try {
                   File result = customGoogleSheetService.getService().files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                           .setFields("id, parents")
                           .execute();
                   System.out.println("File ID: " + result.getId());
                   //return result;
               }catch (Exception ex) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
               }


    {
      "code" : 404,
      "errors" : [ {
        "domain" : "global",
        "location" : "fileId",
        "locationType" : "parameter",
        "message" : "File not found: folderId.",
        "reason" : "notFound"
      } ],
      "message" : "File not found: folderId."
    }
```

Comment: where are you getting the folder id from? did you do a files.list first to ensure that the directory exists?

Comment: I am getting the folderId from the browser link of that folder example: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/folderId, to do a files.list you have to provide a folderId which again shows the fileNotfound error, if I simply do files.list it shows up files which are in the accounts personal drive.

Comment: Why are you using the customGoogleSheetService if you want to use the driveService?

Comment: wrong name, I created a googleSheetService for something else, changed code inside but not the name of the java file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "File not found: folderId.",

Means exactly that the folder id you have supplied is not avalable to the user you are using to run your application.

You are using a service account.  What you need to remember is that service accounts are not you.  A service account is a dummy user that has its own google drive account.

You need to share this folder with the service account.  Take the service account email address into google drive and share that directory with it.  It will then have access to the folder in question.

If you are using gsuite then [Domain wide delication](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#perform_g_suite_domain-wide_delegation_of_authority) needs to be set up properly for the service account to grant it access to the files on the domain.  Do a file.list will tell you once you have set it up properly as it will be able to see the files at that time.

Comment: The service account which I am using is a "Manager" for that shared drive and its folders

Comment: Its not if it doesn't have access to see them. Do a file.list see what it has access to thats when you will know you have set up domain wide delegation properly.

Comment: Ok I'll try this and let you know how it goes

Comment: Ok so I did a simple Files.list.execute(); No setQ, I got one file in return which was "Getting Started" which is the default everyone gets when a new drive account is created, the folder I am trying to upload is in Shared Drive using g-suite, I cannot list the files in the folder I am trying to upload, How do I set permissions properly for the Service account?

Comment: If the service account had access to the files then they would be showing.  There is an issue with your delegation in Gsuite if you are not seeing it i suggest you check that again.

Comment: Hey DalmTo, started working on this again. I did not set the domain wide delegation check box when creating the service account, although now I did check the checkbox, redownloaded the p12 key and replaced it into my mulesoft project, still no matter whichever folder I try, it always comes up with the "File Not Found" message. Is there something I am missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Update: I followed the instructions on here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority

Added 3 drive scopes drive.files, drive, and drive.metadata. No matter whichever folder I try, i cannot upload files, but can upload files if I don't mention the setParents in the java code

Comment: @DalmTo

Update: Assigned the service account to impersonate me as a user of g-suite, I can upload files to my drive and folders, although I cannot upload files to a folder in shared drive, also I have access to that folder in shared drive where I can create and delete files.

Comment: Only filed shared with you by another user will apear in your shared with me folder.  Someone else needs to own the file and grant you permission on it